# Trying to cast a returned HMODULE to a declared IMAGE_DOS_HEADER struct in Python C-Types

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to write some python code (using ctypes) that will eventually allow me to find the IAT.  I'm familiar with the PE structure but have never had to write code to work my way through the data structures to get to it.  I've been doing some research and have found some code written in C++ that allows me to get the a handle to the base image so I can start to dereference my way through the data structures.  I've been using this post [PE Format - IAT Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673754/pe-format-iat-questions) as a reference.  So I'm trying to get a handle to the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER using this post [Get pointer to IMAGE_DOS_HEADER with GetModuleHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126980/get-pointer-to-image-dos-header-with-getmodulehandle) I'm writing this using Python C-types so below is the code that I'm using.

```
class IMAGE_DOS_HEADER(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("e_magic",    WORD),
            ("e_cblp",     WORD),
            ("e_cp",       WORD),
            ("e_crlc",     WORD),
            ("e_cparhdr",  WORD),
            ("e_minalloc", WORD),
            ("e_maxalloc", WORD),
            ("e_ss",       WORD),
            ("e_sp",       WORD),
            ("e_csum",     WORD),
            ("e_ip",       WORD),
            ("e_cs",       WORD),
            ("e_lfarlc",   WORD),
            ("e_ovno",     WORD),
            ("e_res",      WORD * 4),
            ("e_oemid",    WORD),
            ("e_oeminfo",  WORD),
            ("e_res2",     WORD * 10),
            ("e_lfanew",   WORD),
            ]

kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR]

image_dos_header = IMAGE_DOS_HEADER()

hModule = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(0)

if hModule == 0:
   hModule_Error = ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
   print("[-] error getting the hModule " + hModule)
   system.exit(1)

#Trying to cast the handle to image_dos_header struct
image_dos_header = ctypes.byref(hModule)                 #Error is here
```

When I try this code I get the error, "byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'".  I've been doing some research and tried a few things but I can't seem to find an answer.  I've used "byref" before when working with other structs that I've declared using c-types.

Another questions is, I'm able to get what I think is a valid handle returned from the GetModuleHandleW call.  I assume that is the address, if so can I start to work my way through that IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure without having to create the new "image_dos_header" struct and then cast the returned handle to it?  And then work my way through it to make my way to the IAT?  Any help is appreciate or feedback on my methodology I'm trying to use to get to the IAT.  Thanks!

Comment: xref: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2843/245

Answer (score 1):

So I found out what I really wanted to do was to cast an int (Handle address) that was returned from the GetModuleHandleW call to a pointer to a struct (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER).  Below is the code that I used to do that.  Hope it helps someone!

```
#In C++ this would like this - 
#IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pDOSHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)hModule;

pDOSHeader = ctypes.POINTER(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)
pDOSHeader = ctypes.cast(hModule, ctypes.POINTER(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)).contents
```